# Xquery optimization

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have this xquery as follows:

```
declare variable $i := doc()/some-element/modifier[empty(modifier-value)];
$i[1]/../..;
```

I need to run this query on Marklogic's Qconsole where we have 721170811 records. Since that is huge number of record, I am getting timeout error. Is there any way I can optimize this query to get the result?

P.S. I cannot request amdin to increase the timeout time.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating an element range index (or a path range index if the target element is not unique) and using a cts:values() lexicon lookup.

That way, the request can read the values from the range index instead of having to read each document.

See:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon

Comment: Since I cannot request admin is there any way that I can optimize that code from my end?

Comment: With 700 million documents, if you need to run the query frequently, your best strategy is convincing the administrator to add the range index.  Otherwise, one alternative is to use the cts:uris() function, passing the some-element criteria as a cts:query, to collect the document uris in a client. Then, iterate over the list of uris in pages, retrieving the values from one page of documents at a time.  You can use the REST API values endpoint to execute the cts:query and the REST API documents endpoint with a transform to extract the values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xdmp:spawn, create a library when you will make the query, get the documents, iterate the result collecting 1000 documents per iteration and call another xdmp:spawn to process the information from that dataset, I would suggest summarize the result to return only the information you will need to don't crash the browser, at the end should look something like this:

```
xdmp:spawn("process.xqy")
```

into the library  process.xqy

```
function local:start-process(){
   let $docs := (....)
   let $temp := for $x in $docs[$start to $end]
                return local:process-dataset($temp) (: Could use spawn here too if you want :) 
   return xdmp:spawn("collect.xqy",$temp)
}

local:start-process()
```

compact-data function should create a file or a set of files with your data, this way the server will run all the process and in some minutes you will be available to see your data without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to run something like `doc()` or `xdmp:directory` - just returns a result set that will kill you every time.  You need to lower your result set by a lot.

A few thoughts:

1. You want to have as much done in MarkLogic's `d-node`, and the least work done in the `e-node` as possible.  This is a way over-generalization, but for the most part I look at it like `d-node` stuff is data, indexes, lexicon work, etc.  `e-node` stuff handles xQuery and such.  So, in your example, you're definitely working out the `e-node` more than you need to.
2. You're going to want to use `cts:search`, as it uses indexes, not xPath to resolve your query.  So, something like this:

   ```
   declare variable $i := cts:search(fn:collection(), 
     cts:element-query(xs:QName("some-element"), 
       cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("modifier"), "", "exact")
     )
   )[1];
   ```

This will return `document-node`'s, which it looks like what you were wanting with the `$i[1]/../..`.  This searches the xPath `some-element` for a `modifier` that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please create element range index and attribute range index and use cts:search if you are familiar with marklogic it will be easy for you to write the query.